# Load custom js when user reach payment information in magento 1.9 checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, extensions, onepage-checkout

I'm working developing a Magento 1.9 extension and I'm having a hard time trying to load/include a Javascript file in a specific checkout step.

I'm able to include the javascript file in the footer, but I need it to be included when the user reach the "Payment Information step", more precisely, when the payment methods are loaded, as shown in the below print screen.

[image]

I added this code in my extension hoping it would show an alert message when I reach the "Payment Information", but nothing happens...

```
<checkout_onepage_paymentmethod>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello')</script>]]></text>
        </action>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_paymentmethod>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: why do you need it to be loaded at a specific step? it should load on the checkout page and your script should target the event of the payment information step

Comment: I did it this way, @Haim. I'll update my question